# Scrolling List Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I followed the "tutorial" [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27933155/vertical-scroll-bar-in-ul-HTML.html), but it's not working. I'll put all relevant code below. I'm fairly sure the reason it doesn't work is because I have `overflow-y: hidden;` in the body, and the list is contained within the body, so maybe it defaults. However, if I don't do this, the whole page scrolls and not just the list. Thanks so much.

```js
function SearchBar() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
  }
```

```css
body{
  background-color: #081543;
  overflow-y:hidden;
}

p{
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  height: 25%;
  font-size: 25pt;
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-right:30%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#logo{
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 50%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 0px 12px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right: 25%;
}

ul{
  min-height: 200px;
}
#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right: 25%;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block;


}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>

<body>


  <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="SearchBar()" placeholder="type in an item" title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="main.html" onclick=''>apple</a></li>
  <li><a href="main.html" onclick=''>fruit</a></li>
  <li><a href="main.html" onclick=''>shirt</a></li>
  <li><a href="main.html" onclick=''>thing</a></li>
  <li><a href="main.html" onclick=''>stack</a></li>
  <li><a href="main.html" onclick=';'>overflow</a></li>
  <li><a href="main.html" onclick=''>list</a></li>
</ul>



</body>
```

Comment: As stated on duplicate post: `You need to define height of ul or your div and set overflow equals to auto`

Comment: Thanks so much, sorry I didn't see the duplicate post.

Answer (score 0):

Use `height` instead on `min-height` of element `ul`.

```js
function SearchBar() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
  }
```

```css
body{
  background-color: #081543;
  overflow-y:hidden;
}

p{
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  height: 25%;
  font-size: 25pt;
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-right:30%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#logo{
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 50%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 0px 12px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right: 25%;
}

ul{
  height: 150px;
}
#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right: 25%;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block;


}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>

<body>


  <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="SearchBar()" placeholder="type in an item" title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="main.html" onclick=''>apple</a></li>
  <li><a href="main.html" onclick=''>fruit</a></li>
  <li><a href="main.html" onclick=''>shirt</a></li>
  <li><a href="main.html" onclick=''>thing</a></li>
  <li><a href="main.html" onclick=''>stack</a></li>
  <li><a href="main.html" onclick=';'>overflow</a></li>
  <li><a href="main.html" onclick=''>list</a></li>
</ul>



</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the scrollbar to appear you need to make the height of `ul` smaller than the height of its children elements, so there is content to be scrolled towards. You can also hide the horizontal scrolbar by using `overflow-y: auto` instead of `overflow: auto`.

```js
function SearchBar() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #081543;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

p {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  height: 25%;
  font-size: 25pt;
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-right: 30%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#logo {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 0px 12px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right: 25%;
}

ul {
  height: 200px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right: 25%;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block;
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>

<body>


  <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="SearchBar()" placeholder="type in an item" title="Type in a name">

  <ul id="myUL">
    <li><a href="main.html" onclick=''>apple</a></li>
    <li><a href="main.html" onclick=''>fruit</a></li>
    <li><a href="main.html" onclick=''>shirt</a></li>
    <li><a href="main.html" onclick=''>thing</a></li>
    <li><a href="main.html" onclick=''>stack</a></li>
    <li><a href="main.html" onclick=';'>overflow</a></li>
    <li><a href="main.html" onclick=''>list</a></li>
  </ul>



</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your indication would be correct, that the body overflow:hidden is causing the issue. However, I've noticed as well that in the css for your ul that you have a min-height. All this will do is continue to increase the size of your ul past the point of the body whereupon it would be hidden.

The purpose of a scroll is to enable you to view content when the height or width of the content exceeds the boundaries of the element it is in - by including a min-height, it never exceeds those boundaries, instead increasing them.

Change your ul min-height to height and you will be fine :) Hope that helps!